# API for driving directions given two coordinates

Tags: maps, google-maps

I'm looking to simply find driving time (and distance) between two sets of coordinates. I don't know much about openmaps, but was wondering if I can host a server that allows me to quickly get driving time and distance. I'm looking to show 5-10 different waypoints so a user can see the driving time between them.

I see that openmaps is a "tile server", but do I need that to be able to get driving directions? Looking for some documentation to understand that and other open source platforms a bit better.

I am not interested in using google for this project as we are already using them for another project.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend giving a try to TomTom Routing API.
The API is quite easy to understand. You can do 2.5k routing request per day for free.

Documentation: https://developer.tomtom.com/routing-api/routing-api-documentation

And API Explorer: https://developer.tomtom.com/content/routing-api-explorer